# Upgrading CentOS 8 with an existing RAID?

Tags: centos, raid

I have a software RAID running on another distribution of Linux and are upgrading the server to CentOS 8.

I've only configured a server in the past when there was no data on the boot device or software RAID. How do I upgrading just the boot device to CentOS 8 so it will recognize the existing software RAID?

Comment: is this hardware raid (PCI card with its own ram & battery and disks attached here)  ? bios raid ? soft raid ?  in only the first case this is transparent.  bios raid I consider that as soft raid ... so dangerous ...  Knowing this  now if you backuped your data start installation open a terminal (suspend install) load raid tools & detect it as a /dev/mdxx device  go back to installation & continue it at disk setup moment you should have your raid device  displayed as target disk.

Comment: I mentioned it was a software RAID, but I added the work "software" two more times so there is no confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with centos8:

- during installation do not do anything that will touch the software raid drive components
- install the mdadm package
- edit `/etc/fstab` to mount the raid (copy fstab line in current fstab)
- reboot

You don't need an `/etc/mdadm.conf` and the boot process autodetects and assembles md devices (unless you have an exotic config).

Make sure your backups are up to date before beginning.

Comment: considering original Linux configuration is undetermined… Your solution risks thrashing system completely, left one with only option to reassemble everything back using another live system (hdd/dvd/net etc.).
Don't suggest to experiment with that without sufficient knowledge.
Set up of another OS from native environment next migrating to new one is much more predictable and maintainable approach

Comment: @Mark Wagner When completed, how can I test this to make sure it worked and can proceed? mdadm --detail?

Answer (score 0):

Stable solution for migration to any other OS flavor would be:

- disassemble your RAID to free up some of your block devices (BD) for a new OS;
- set up new OS solely to dedicated BDs (set up incomplete/fail-state RAID within there if required);
- migrate mandatory OS/user data to new semi-RAID BDs;
- switch to new OS & reassemble your RAID again.

In case your RAID structure can deal with that (I.e. not RAID-1 or alike without any redundancy).